# How to use flake8 as unittest case?

Tags: python, flake8

I want to make `flake8` a unittest case for all my source files. The unittest have to fail when the code is not PEP8 conform.

I still do this with `pycodestyle` that way.

```
pep = pycodestyle.Checker(filename)
return pep.check_all() == 0
```

But I don't know how to do this with `flake8` after `import flake8`.

Comment: I would not do this as part of unit tests, but rather, as a separate process that also has to pass before code can be merged or published.

Comment: Please explain why. But by the way this wouldn't answer my primary question. ;)

Comment: You definitely don't want that as part of the unit tests, but as part of [pre-commit checks](https://pre-commit.com/), here is [flake8's hook](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/using-hooks.html). Unit test should allow "ugly" code as you're only testing functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this is not something you should be doing in unit tests. Unit tests should be used to check behavior and functionality of the code, something like linting and code style enforcement is best left to pre-commit checks or CI. The `flake8` documentation has instructions on [version control integration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/using-hooks.html) where you can see how to integrate it with [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/)

But if you **REALLY** want to do it your way for some reason, you can see the documentation for [legacy flake8 python api](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/python-api.html). And you can do something like

```py
from flake8.api import legacy as flake8

style_guide = flake8.get_style_guide(
    ignore=['E24', 'W5'],
    select=['E', 'W', 'F'],
    format     ='pylint',
)

result = style_guide.input_file("filename")
if result.total_errors:
    # do whatever you want here. Raise errors or whatever.
    pass
```

Comment: a note, it's "legacy" and will be going away at some point when I replace it with something better -- but yeah you probably don't want to run linting in your tests

Comment: @AnothonySottile Do you have an open Ticket/Issue/PR about the replacement I can subscribe to?